# Print media universal (*) rule gets overridden on footer element

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-specificity

I have been searching around trying to find an answer for my question, but simply couldn't find anyone else with my problem, so I decided to turn to stack overflow.

I'm adding CSS rules for @media print and stumbled on a problem that I can't understand. I'm trying to use the * selector to apply background-color: white to all elements, but some elements ignore the rule and continue using the previously defined color, overriding the print media rule.

Here's the simplest CSS file that can reproduce the problem:

```css
footer {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media print {
    * {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

And in my HTML I have simple footer tags without any classes or IDs.

```html
...
<footer>
    Footer content here
</footer>
...
```

I've checked the validity of both, the HTML and the CSS, so it shouldn't be a syntax error

What happens is that if I use Chrome Developer tools option *Emulate CSS Media: print* or print preview with *Background colors and images* checked, the footer element retains its light blue color.

If I inspect the element with the Developer tools, it shows the @media print rule has been overridden:

<strike>background-color: white;</strike>

I can't understand why the footer rule above overrides the * rule. As far as I know, these two rules are of the same specificity, so the one that comes last should be the one applied. But that's not what happens. It works if I edit the rule under the media query to explicitly state that the rule should be applied on footer elements as well:

```css
*, footer {
    background-color: white;
}
```

But for me that seems really weird, as I thought the * already includes the footer element. I could of course just use the CSS with the footer specified in the rule, but I'd still really want to know *why* the asterisk alone isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a media query, it is like an if statement in that if the conditions listed apply, it includes the styles in that block. However, they aren't given a higher specificity just because they're in a media query. The * selector will always have a lower specificity than footer regardless of where it is written.

This, [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity), has probably the most comprehensive breakdown of CSS specificity. If you look under "Important Notes" you'll see the specificity of the * is 0,0,0,0 and the footer is 0,0,0,1. You can also check out this, [crimsondesigns.com/blog/…](https://joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/) (Gotcha #4) that discusses specificity issues with media queries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your scopes

```
/* global scope */
footer {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
/* media-print scope */
@media print {
    * {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Since you defined `background-color` for `footer` in the global scope and `footer > *` (has higher priority because its more specific) it overwrites your global background-color.

---

**Try the following to fix it** (*did not test it*):

```css
@media screen {
  footer {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}

@media print {
  * {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried your code, and while it does fix the color for the developer tools print css emulation, opening the actual print preview with *Background colors and images* or *Background graphics* checked reveals, that the rule is actually still being overridden. Also, from what I've read about media queries, I've never before heard that the scopes would have different priorities. As far as I know, the media queries are more like if statements - the code inside them is either read or not depending on the media.

Comment: When you use a media query, it is like an if statement in that if the conditions listed apply, it includes the styles in that block. However, they aren't given a higher specificity just because they're in a media query. The * selector will always have a lower specificity than footer regardless of where it is written.

Comment: @dukedevil294 So this has to do with the specificity of the * selector? I tried finding information about that, but somehow got the impression that using the selector has no effect on specificity and thus footer and * would have the same specificity, in which case the one declared later in the file should be applied. But was I wrong? Could you point me to a reputable source on the information of the specificity of the * selector?

Comment: This, https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/, has probably the most comprehensive breakdown of CSS specificity. If you look under "Important Notes" you'll see the specificity of the * is 0,0,0,0 and the footer is 0,0,0,1. You can also check out this, http://www.crimsondesigns.com/blog/css3-media-queries-simple-gotchas-easy-fixes/ (Gotcha #4) that discusses specificity issues with media queries.

Comment: @dukedevil294 Okay, now I understand. I had read somewhere that "universal selector has no effect on specificity" and thought that it meant selecting by using * has the same specificity as selecting an element directly. Could you post the information about the specificity as an answer to the question, so I could mark it as the solution?

Comment: @lcl I added my comments and links as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is correct, just to be safe I would rather do `background-color: transparent` (I don't think printers actually PRINTS white color though..).

```
footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

@media print {
  * {
    background-color: transparent; 
    /* Try emulating using this: 'background-color: transparent !important;', seems chrome emulator isn't respecting this without the !important rule. */
  }
}
```

I tested **your** code, it seems to be an issue with the dev tools emulator. When I emulated print, the footer still had the background-color. But when I actually pressed "print" in my web browser, the background was white as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, the problem actually exists in printing as well. You just don't see it right away. That's because, by default, most browsers ignore all background colors and images when printing. If you're using Chrome there's a checkbox labeled something like *Background colors and images* or *Background graphics* under *Options*. If you check that, then the color is visible, meaning that my rule is not being applied.

But yeah, you're right about the color that I should use, I changed it to transparent, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at HTML5Boilerplate's print CSS:
https://github.com/h5bp/html5boilerplate.com/blob/master/src/css/_print.css